# Trigger serverside event with regular HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, events, webforms

I have the following ASP.NET Webform code located in a usercontrol with a couple of inputs :

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBLogin" CssClass="floatRightclear" runat="server" ImageUrl=""
                OnClick="imgBLogin_Click" ValidationGroup="Login" />
```

This will trigger a sumbmit to imgBLogin_Click on server.

Now I need to generate a special made submit button(flying doors) and the question is how this is done in plain HTML? Is it possible?

In this case I got a helper class that will generate proper HTML for a linked button :

```
<%= Helpers.ButtonLink("Skapa konto", ResolveUrl("~/sites/" + this.Page.Theme + "/common/createProfile.aspx") , "btn1", style: "float:right;" ) %>
```

I need to do the same with the submit button(imagebutton).

Comment: You're asking what HTML an imageButton generates?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your question 100%, but i believe you want to fire a server-side event after doing some HTML/JS work?

Anyway, the only way to fire server-side event from client side is by using JavaScript.

You can add an ASP button and set css visibility to hidden(`style="display:none;"`) ,Not asp.net Visible attribute.

Then you add a onclick attribute to the HTML element you want to fire the event 
(eg.: `<a href="#" onclick"fnFireEvent()>Click Here</a>` )

Then your javascript part would be:

```
<script> 
function fnFireEvent()
{
  $("#<%=btnFireEvent.ClientID %>").click(); //your asp.net button that you set visibility to hidden earlier.
}
</script>
```

Then at the server side event you can do what you want to do.

Hope this helps.